# Remote for LG TV, LG Soundbar, and TiVo box

Tags: remote-control, television

I lost my LG sound bar remote before I moved.  Prior to moving I had DIRECTV and could use their remote to control the volume on the sound bar while performing all of the satellite functionalities I needed.

After moving I switched providers, this company uses TiVo.  When they came and set everything up the remote was not programmed for the sound bar.  I tried manually setting it but wasn't able to find the correct codes as well as finding the specific remote model that they gave me.

Is there a specific universal remote control that will allow me to connect to my TV, sound bar, and TiVo receiver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to consolidate remote controls, I always recommend a [Logitech Harmony](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/harmony-remotes). There are various models that have additional features (ie. touch screens, how many devices it can control at once, quick setup, etc.)

One awesome thing about all models of the Harmony, is that they all use the same database for compatibility. You can search if your devices are available: [here](https://support.myharmony.com/en-gb/compatibility?utm_source=logitech.com&utm_medium=promo&utm_content=pdp%20-%20footer&utm_campaign=compatibility%20lookup&WT.ac=ps%7C11364%7Clphmcomp-CTA1). Logitech boasts of [compatibility](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Harmony-Remotes/Harmony-Remote-FAQ-Misunderstandings-and-Tips/td-p/211978) with 250K+ devices across 7K manufacturers. Chances are high that it is compatible by default. If not, you can still program it using a device's original remote.

Personally, I have the [Harmony 650](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/harmony-remote-650?crid=60).

[image: Harmony 650]

I use it to control a television, receiver, bluray player and stereo. Set up of each device to use the Harmony takes a little bit of time but once a the Harmony knows the device and the on/off macros I use to get everything on and how I want it when I sit to relax, it's very nice.